# Handling multiple cell selection and custom transitions

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation, uicollectionviewcell

We use a `UICollectionView` in this example but the same issue would apply to a `UITableView` approach.

We have a custom animation on the collection view cell when it is selected. It animates the cell out, then we have a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Within this method we have some custom animation code, once the animation is complete we then trigger the segue (which is a custom transition).

**Issue**
The issue is when you quickly select two cells the animation occurs for both and then messes up the transition/navigation bar.

What is the best way to handle only one animation occurring at a time in this case? Disabling mutli select would not change anything as in theory we are not selecting multiple just quickly select one then another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (self.cellAnimationInProgress == YES) {
            return;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            //Code here is run on the main thread
            self.cellAnimationInProgress = YES;
        });
```

I used a similar approach to suggested above. Where I keep a BOOL and update to YES during the animation out. Then when returning and animating back in once that is complete the BOOL is updated back to NO so the second tap is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Set the allowsSelection property for your collection view to NO, in didSelectItemAtIndexPath; that should prevent the user from selecting a second cell. You can set it to YES in viewDidAppear, if you're coming back to this same collection view later from the controller you're segueing to.

Comment: Thanks I tried that initially and it did not work for me. Possibly because it was not called on the main thread. In the end I just added a BOOL that I update when animating out and back to NO when coming back into the controller and animating back. I guess that is the best way right?

Comment: @StuartM, I don't know if it's the best way. If you set allowsSelection to NO as the first line in didSelectItemAtIndexPath, it should be called on the main thread. Without knowing what you tried it's hard to comment further.